# Testing laravel repository which has model as a dependency

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, mockery

Problem is that i can't test one function, because it is touching other functions of the same repository.

1. Do I need to test one function in isolation from other functions in same repository, or it is normal that one function can access other functions in same repository ?
2. If function needs to be tested in isolation from other, how it can be done, because I don't understand how I can mock repository in which I'm working. I understand how to mock dependencies, but how to mock other functions in same repository ?
3. Am I mocking model correctly in setUp method in the test?

**Code:**

Real world binding of and repository:

```
// Bind User repository interface
$app->bind('MyApp\Repositories\User\UserInterface', function () {
    return new EloquentUser(new User);
});
```

**EloquentUser.php:**

```
public function __construct(Model $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}

public function findById($id)
{
    return $this->user->find($id);
}

public function replace($data)
{
    $user = $this->findById($data['user']['id']);

    // If user not exists, create new one with defined values.
    if ( ! $user) {
        return $this->create($data);
    } else {
        return $this->update($data);
    }
}

public function create($data)
{
    $user = $this->user->create($data['user']);

    if ($user) {

        return $this->createProfile($user, $data['profile']);

    } else {

        return false;
    }
}

private function createProfile($user, $profile)
{
    return $user->profile()->create($profile);
}

public function update($user, $data)
{
    foreach ($data['user'] as $key => $value) {
        $user->{$key} = $value;
    }

    if (isset($data['profile']) && count($data['profile']) > 0) {

        foreach ($data['profile'] as $key => $value) {
            $user->profile->$key = $value;
        }
    }

    return ($user->push()) ? $user : false;
}
```

**EloquentUserTest.php**

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->user = Mockery::mock('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model', 'MyApp\Models\User\User');
    App::instance('MyApp\Models\User\User', $this->user);
    $this->repository = new EloquentUser($this->user);
}

public function testReplaceCallsCreateMethod()
{
    $data = [
        'user' => [
            'id' => 1,
            'email' => 'test@test.com',
        ],
        'profile' => [
            'name' => 'John Doe',
            'image' => 'abcdef.png',
        ],
    ];

    // Mock the "find" call that is made in findById()
    $this->user->shouldReceive('find')->once()->andReturn(false);

    // Mock the "create" call that is made in create() method
    $this->user->shouldReceive('create')->once()->andReturn(true);

    // Run replace method that i want to test
    $result = $this->repository->replace($data);

    $this->assertInstanceOf('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model', $result, 'Should be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model');
}
```

**When running this test I got:**

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function profile() on a non-object in C:\Htdocs\at.univemba.com\uv2\app\logic\Univemba\Repositories\User\EloquentUser.php on line 107
```

So it means that Test is trying to touch function in EloquentUser.php:

```
private function createProfile($user, $profile)
{
    return $user->profile()->create($profile);
}
```

Do I need to mock createProfile ? because profile() cant be found. And if I need to do this, how can i do it because this function is in same repository that i'm testing?

Answer (score 7):

Question is solved.
Just needed to create one more Model instance and pass it in mocked method.

**My Working setUp method:**

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    $this->user = Mockery::mock('MyApp\Models\User\User');

    App::instance('MyApp\Models\User\User', $this->user);

    $this->repository = new EloquentUser($this->user);
}
```

**Working test method:**

```
public function testReplaceCallsCreateMethod()
{
    $data = [
        'user' => [
            'id' => 1,
            'email' => 'test@test.com',
            'password' => 'plain',
        ],
        'profile' => [
            'name' => 'John Doe',
            'image' => 'abcdef.png',
        ],
    ];

    // Mock Model's find method
    $this->user->shouldReceive('find')->once()->andReturn(false);

    // Create new Model instance
    $mockedUser = Mockery::mock('MyApp\Models\User\User');

    // Mock Models profile->create and pass Model as a result of a function
    $mockedUser->shouldReceive('profile->create')->with($data['profile'])->andReturn($mockedUser);

    // Pass second instance Model as a result
    $this->user->shouldReceive('create')->once()->andReturn($mockedUser);

    // Now all $user->profile is properly mocked and will return correct data
    $result = $this->repository->replace($data);

    $this->assertInstanceOf('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model', $result, 'Should be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model');
}
```